# Common text replace use regex

Tags: scala

I am doing some word analysis and use regex to match some words I don't need and replace them to "",example:

```
some common context here as single_word;
```

My goal is to replace `as single_word ;` part to "" , so it would be like:

```
some common context here
```

My regex is `as\s[\w]*\p{L}*\w[\w.]*(\s+)?;` and I test it fine, but it would not work in scala,which code is :

```
 sentence.trim.replaceAll(s"as\\s[\\w]*\\p{L}*\\w[\\w.]*(\\s+)?;", "") .
```

Following is my test, which worked out fine, but in scala, it won't work
[image]

Comment: What do you mean "it won't work"? What is it doing instead?

Comment: To clarify, `"some common context here as single_word;".trim.replaceAll(s"as\\s[\\w]*\\p{L}*\\w[\\w.]*(\\s+)?;", "")` returns `res0: String = "some common context here "` for me. I don't know what you could've done to make it return anything different, short of mistyping it.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have pattern

```
val pattern ="as\\s[\\w]*\\p{L}*\\w[\\w.]*(\\s+)?;"
val str = "some common context here as single_word;  "
str.replaceAll(pattern,"")
```

In scala worksheet, you get an output as

```
pattern: String = as\s[\w]*\p{L}*\w[\w.]*(\s+)?;
str: String = some common context here as single_word;  
res0: String = some common context here
```

Answer (score 0):

In REPL

```
scala> val pattern ="as .*;"
pattern: String = as .*;

scala> val str = "some common context here as single_word;  "
str: String = "some common context here as single_word;  "

scala> str.replaceAll(pattern,"")
res3: String = "some common context here   "

scala>
```

Comment: There's no point in making it a capture group. `"as .*"` works fine.